# From within Excel how do I change an active PowerPoint presentation without switching focus?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I use macro's to export objects to PowerPoint from Excel. I have the option to choose which currently open presentation I would like to export to. However when I switch presentations is there a way to stop the focus switching from Excel to PowerPoint? My code is below:

```
Function SetActivePresentation(Filename As String) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer

    ' This just checks if PowerPoint is loaded - not needed for the question
    If Me.Load = False Then
        SetActivePresentation = False
    End If

    ' Loop through the PowerPoint windows
    For i = 1 To Me.pPowerpoint.Windows.Count
        If Me.pPowerpoint.Windows(i).Presentation.name = Filename Then
            Me.pPowerpoint.Windows(i).Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    SetActivePresentation = True

End Function
```

and this is the `pPowerPoint` method in the class:

```
Public pPowerpoint As Object

Public Property Get PowerPoint() As Object
    PowerPoint = pPowerpoint
End Property
```

and finally my Load function:

```
Function Load() As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Set the PowerPoint object
    Set pPowerpoint = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    ' Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If

    Load = True

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

    Load = False

End Function
```

Then from elsewhere in my code and I can export Excel objects by looping through PowerPoint slides in this manner `For Each slide In PowerPoint.pPowerpoint.ActivePresentation.Slides`, where `PowerPoint` is my PowerPoint class referenced above.

Comment: what do you need by `switching`, `Activating`? as far as I know it is not required to activate PP for most of the actions. What do you do in the other part of code?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor because then I can call the `ActivePresentation` object and export Excel objects

Comment: You would just prefix with pPowerpoint.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav prefix what?

Comment: I'd dome some work in looking at how to use objects and use other office applications, prefix anything to do with power point as being the result of your getobject, like this pPowerpoint.ActivePresentation.Slides no PowerPoint

Comment: I still can't see the other part of your code but I still think you don't need to use `activepresentation` if you work with `object variable`. Moreover, changing active presentation can be done event if PowerPoint is in `.Visible = false` mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its somewhat confusing about *..change an active PowerPoint presentation without switching focus..*. But from the discussion in question's comments show that the real problem is to **export** Excel objects without **focus** on Powerpoint. To solve that you can avoid using `ActivePresentation` object. How? one simple solution is by using global variable..

This code bellow shows how its done..

```
'Global variables
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

'searching for presentation (function/sub)
For i = 1 To Me.pPowerpoint.Windows.Count
    If Me.pPowerpoint.Windows(i).Presentation.name = Filename Then
        'dont activate! Me.pPowerpoint.Windows(i).Activate
        Set pptPres = Me.pPowerpoint.Windows(i).Presentation
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'copy object "Char 1" at "Sheet1"
'by accessing the global variable (other function/sub)
Set objChart = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
objChart.ChartArea.Copy
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
pptSlide.Shapes.Paste
```